# "Build a Tribute Page" - Задание

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Выполняю задание на *freecodecamp*. Выполнил его несколько по своему, нужно ли делать в точности как в задании, или подобный способ тоже подойдет?

- То, что [сделал я](http://codepen.io/Tvarinskyy/pen/aWbdyJ)
- [Нужный результат.](https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/full/NNvBQW/)

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="background">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1 class="text-center">Gabe Logan Newell</h1>
                    <h3 class="text-center">Генеральный директор Valve inc.</h3>
                </div>
                <center><div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://last-gamer.com/uploads/posts/2013-09/1379468313_geyb-nyuell-steam.jpg">
                    <p class="text-center photo">Гейб родился 03 ноября 1962 - (54 года)</p>
                </div></center>
                <div class=" col-md-offset-1">
                    <h3 class="bio">События в жизни Гейба:</h3>
                    <ul class="bio">
                        <li><b>1962</b> - Рожден в Сиэтл, Вашингтон, США</li>
                        <li><b>1998</b> - Вышла серия игр Half-Life, ставшая основой для таких популярных игр и модификаций как Counter-Strike и Team Fortress Classic.</li>
                        <li><b>2000</b> - Харрингтон покинул компанию, после чего Ньюэлл выкупил его долю.</li>
                        <li><b>2007</b> - Ньюэлл открыто выразил своё недовольство различными ограничениями игровых консолей, с которыми сталкиваются разработчики игр. В частности, он негативно отметил политику Sony по отношению к системе PlayStation 3</li>
                        <li><b>2010</b> - В декабре журнал Forbes включил Гейба Ньюэлла в свой список людей, которые в 2011 году окажут существенное влияние в сфере своего бизнеса.</li>
                        <li><b>2012</b> - Ньюэлл вошёл в список самых богатых людей мира по версии журнала Forbes, заняв 854 место в мире и 303 место в США. По оценкам экспертов, его заработок в это время составлял 1,5 миллиарда долларов.</li>
                    </ul>
                    <h4 class="bio">Женат на Лизe Hьюэлл, имеет двух сыновей.

                    Ньюэлл страдал дистрофией Фукса — врождённым заболеванием, при котором разрушается роговица глаза, и в какой-то момент его зрение упало до критического уровня, но две операции по пересадке роговицы вернули ему зрение. «Я не просто стал снова видеть, я стал видеть лучше, чем когда бы то ни было. Я будто бы оказался в волшебной сказке. Тогда до меня дошло, насколько быстро наступает будущее», — вспоминает Ньюэлл.

                    В числе любимых игр Ньюэлл называл Super Mario 64, Doom и Star Trek, в которые он играл на системе Burroughs. Игра Doom убедила его в том, что видеоигры являются многообещающим будущим в сфере развлечений, а Super Mario 64 доказала ему, что игры тоже являются искусством. Ньюэлл являлся подписчиком популярной MMORPG игры от Blizzard Entertainment — World of Warcraft. Ньюэлл заявил, что является поклонником анимационного сериала Дружба — это чудо.

                    По совету друга в качестве хобби Ньюэлл занялся слесарным делом. Вместо машины он поставил в гараже шлифовальный и фрезерный станки, а также бочки с солью для воронения стали. В свободное время Ньюэлл делает и обрабатывает приспособления и игрушки вроде подставок для iPad и мечей. «Мне показалось, что это хороший отдых после постоянного сидения перед экраном», — поясняет Ньюэлл</h4>

                    <p class="small">— Ньюэлл, Гейб (англ. Gabe Newell, настоящее имя Гейб Логан Ньюэлл — англ. Gabe Logan Newell; род. 18 июля 1962)</p>

                    <h3 class="bio">Подробнее вы можете прочитать о Гейбе <a href="https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%BB,_%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B1">здесь.</a></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer class="text-center">
                <hr>
                <p>Написан и разработан<a href="https://vk.com/meowwiza" target="_blanck"> Иваном Б.</a></p>
            </footer>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.background {
    background: #eee;
    max-width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 80%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.photo {
    padding-top: 2%;
}

.timeline {
    margin-left: 35%;
}

ul.bio {
    max-width: 80%;
}

h3.bio {
    margin-left: 5%;
}

h4.bio {
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    max-width: 90%;
}

p.small {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #777;
    max-width: 650px
}
```

Comment: там же в задание пишут вроде требования?

Comment: @qpeela требование одно - возвести подобную страницу, страница схожа, адаптивна вроде, вот и думаю.

Comment: CSS тут и в примере на http://codepen.io/Tvarinskyy/pen/aWbdyJ разный

Comment: @labris - решил переделать. Вопрос не актуален.